# RE: Internal Transfer Issue / Difficult Boss - Can HR take back a transfer that was supposedly in place?

Tags: communication, human-resources, unprofessional-behavior, internal-transfer, micro-management

When I started at this job, I was not given proper training and orientation as promised. Although, I may know and have skills for the position I am in, I know that I still need to learn how they do things around here. Soon after I started working here, it became very apparent to me that I am dealing with a difficult boss. It is very uncomfortable to work with her.

It's like walking on an egg shells. She would give me wrong information about work, send me to the wrong people, which often resulted in embarrassing myself in the process. There have been incidents where I'd get yelled at and confronted like a child in front of my colleagues. She's dismissive and passive-aggressive when she communicates whether its via email, phone or in staff meetings. She'd give my co-worker the credit for the work she knew full well I did. I caught her in a lie on more than one occasion, she deleted files I had created on teams. These are just a couple of examples of what she does or have done among other things. And when I tried to ask her about the deleted files, or things I worked on that were missing, confronted her with evidence when she tried to lie.  I was ignored, and again dismissed. Her uncivil behavior is so apparent and unbearable, it feels more like bullying. I have moments where it feels like she's setting me up for failure. Oh btw, she works remotely 5 days a week.

I tried to reach out to our Boss to fix these issues I was having with her but to no avail.  So I decided to go to my union.

My union reps decided that we go to HR because our boss ignored my complaint about her.  I have asked HR to investigate her and her unprofessional hostile behavior, I even encouraged them to verify an incident I reported because I have a witness to corroborate what happened my witness said HR never called her to ask about it.

The micro aggression from the difficult boss continued to escalate to macro aggressions.  All of which was being documented and reported to my union rep.  Eventually, HR came up with a solution to transfer me internally to a different department which was good news to me.  HR had told me to wrap things up from this current place to get ready for the new dept.  They sent me an email confirming the department I am going to, who my bosses are going to be and when.

I was ecstatic about it.  Only to find out two days before the transfer that it is on hold indefinitely. They sent me an email response when I asked for my office location.  They're saying that new department I was going to, decided they want to hire their own (my position). I have a feeling that something happened behind closed door and that the real reason is different from what they were telling me. I have a theory that it might have something to do with another employee from my department getting transferred a week before me. Had I been transferred too, they wouldn't have anyone who knows how to do my job and or hers, and  the processes. The department will suffer.

Anyway, this has just been devastating to me. Can HR do that? Can they pull back a transfer that's already been offered and confirmed?

Also, apart from me, I found out that there are two (2) other people in my department have also brought complaints to HR against her for the same issues. Is there a way to demote or petition for her to be demoted? Or just simply push her out of her position? She's just really a horrible boss. I apologize, I may not be asking the right questions here but...

Any advice helps.

Comment: Please edit this so it is less of a rant and contains an indication of what your actual goal is here; at the moment, there's nothing we can help with.

Comment: So either you get a different internal transfer or you have to consider a different option like leave.

Comment: Since you have already gone to the union, take it back to the union and ask them to escalate it.

Answer (score 1):

In the US, a company can do pretty much whatever it wants within the law unless bound by a collective bargaining agreement ("Union Contract").  A company can agree to transfer you to a new job today and completely change that tomorrow.  There is nothing stopping a company from being unprofessional, from micro-managing, or from just plain treating its employees badly.

Comment: And it's unclear that they *were* being unprofessional, micromanaging, or treating the employee badly. They had a solution in mind. That particular solution didn't work out. THAT HAPPENS. The proper answer is to calmly say "I'd still like a transfer, what else is available?"